# Snap svg неправильно вычисляет длину path

Tags: html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, snapsvg

[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/CodingJediKnight/rgkLh7f3/).

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию для 'path', используя атрибуты `dasharray` \ `dashoffset`.
Но `Snap Svg` неправильно вычисляет длину `path`.

`Svg` изображение, создано с помощью составного контура в `Adobe Illustrator`.
Я что-то неправильно делаю, или это `bug`, о котором я должен сообщить?

Есть ли способ рассчитать длину правильно?

```js
/*First svg*/
var path = Snap('#svg path');
var pathLength = Snap.path.getTotalLength(path); //calc length

path.attr({
  "stroke-dashoffset": 0,
  "stroke-dasharray": pathLength
});

$("#total").text(pathLength);

/*path.animate({"stroke-dashoffset": pathLength}, 3500, mina.ease);*/
Snap.animate(0, pathLength, function(value) {
  path.attr({
    'stroke-dashoffset': value
  });
  $("#len").text(value);
}, 5000, mina.easeinout);

/*Second svg*/
var path2 = Snap('#svg2 path');
var selectedLength = 112; //select length by playing with styles in browser
path2.attr({
  "stroke-dashoffset": 0,
  "stroke-dasharray": selectedLength
});

$("#total2").text(selectedLength);

Snap.animate(0, selectedLength, function(value) {
  path2.attr({
    'stroke-dashoffset': value
  });
  $("#len2").text(value);
}, 5000, mina.easeinout);
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#svg,
#svg2 {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.body:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="wrap">
    <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
            <path class="st0" d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div>Length calc by Snap.path.getTotalLength</div>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <div>Stroke dashoffset during animation</div>
    <div id="len"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="wrap">
    <svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
            <path class="st0" d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div>Length selected by me testing in browser</div>
    <div id="total2"></div>
    <div>Stroke dashoffset during animation</div>
    <div id="len2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this resource, it is customary to ask and answer questions in Russian. Ask a question in Russian, or go to the English version of the resource.

Comment: @CodingJediKnight Если позаимствовали вопрос на enSO.могу предложить помощь в переводе. Вопрос интересный и я кажется знаю, как на него ответить

Comment: Извиняюсь, не знал, что тут по регионам. Нет, вопрос мой и пример мной сделанный.

Comment: @CodingJediKnight, Тогда стоит либо перевести текст на русский, либо перенести сам вопрос на enSO

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Только зарегистрировался. Не знаю всех нюансов. А можно задать 2 вопроса и на русском и на английском? Или это дурной тон?

Comment: @CodingJediKnight не надо дублировать. Уже перевожу :-)

Comment: _А можно задать 2 вопроса и на русском и на английском?_ - можно. Для [задания вопросов на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), для [задания вопросов на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо Alexandr_T. Он объяснил с точки зрения теории почему анимация ломалась. Я переписал составной `path` в несколько маленьких `path`ов. Начало каждого `path`а начинается с d="M..." (moveto). Правки сделал в блокноте. Вот код с использованием Snap SVG.

```js
/*First svg*/
var path = Snap('#svg path');
var pathLength = Snap.path.getTotalLength(path); //calc length

path.attr({
    "stroke-dashoffset": 0,
    "stroke-dasharray": pathLength
});

$("#total").text(pathLength);

/*path.animate({"stroke-dashoffset": pathLength}, 3500, mina.ease);*/
Snap.animate(0, pathLength, function(value) {
    path.attr({
        'stroke-dashoffset': value
    });
    $("#len").text(value);
}, 5000, mina.easeinout);

/*Second svg*/
var svg2 = Snap('#svg2');
var paths = svg2.selectAll("path");
var maxLength = 0;
var tempLength = 0;

for (key in paths.items) {
    tempLength = Snap.path.getTotalLength(paths.items[key]);
    if (maxLength < tempLength) {
        maxLength = tempLength;
    }
}

svg2.attr({
    "stroke-dashoffset": 0,
    "stroke-dasharray": maxLength
});

$("#total2").text(maxLength);

Snap.animate(0, maxLength, function(value) {
    svg2.attr({
        'stroke-dashoffset': value
    });
    $("#len2").text(value);
}, 5000, mina.easeinout);
```

```css
.wrap {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#svg,
#svg2 {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.body:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.panel {
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
    <div class="wrap">
        <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
            <path class="st0" d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div>Length calc by getTotalLength() from combined path</div>
        <div id="total"></div>
        <div>Stroke dashoffset during animation</div>
        <div id="len"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="wrap">
        <svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60" >
            <path d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
            c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7"/>
            <path d="M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4"/>
            <path d="M58.2,42.2h-2.6
            c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
            c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
            c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
            c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
            l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
            c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
            c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z"/>
            <path d="M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
            s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z"/>
            <path d="M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
            c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59"/>
            <path d="M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44"/>
            <path d="M5,5h12"/>
            <path d="M20.4,5h4"/>
            <path d="M5,9h20"/>
            <path d="M55,19H35"/>
            <path d="M45,23
            H29"/>
            <path d="M55,28H29"/>
            <path d="M35,32h-6"/>
            <path d="M55,23h-6"/>
            <path d="M0.9,23H5"/>
            <path d="M0.9,32.7H5"/>
            <path d="M0.9,42H5"/>
            <path d="M0.9,51.8H5"/>
            <path d="M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1"/>
            <path d="M20.3,59V26.6"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div>I rewrite compound path to small paths. Begining of each path is d="M..." (moveto)</div>
        <div>Max length of svg paths getted by getTotalLength();</div>
        <div id="total2"></div>
        <div>Stroke dashoffset during animation</div>
        <div id="len2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Анимация svg изображения, нарисованная одним пером. Между анимациями нет паузы.

```html
<svg  id="Rein" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="228" height="366" viewBox="274.99 129 114 183" >
<title>animation Reindeer</title> 
    
 <g>
      <path  stroke-width="0.8" stroke="saddlebrown" stroke-dasharray="953" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m344 129c-2 0-5 3-6 4-5 6-2 10 2 15 4 5 8 8 12 12-1 0-2 1-3 2-5-6-10-5-15-3 4 4 4 9 14 11l3 20c2 11 1 10-5 13-7 3-18 4-31 1-8-4-17-5-24-2l0 0c-3-2-5-6-6-11-3 5-5 9 0 15-1 6-4 12-3 18 2 15 6 16 4 18-3 4-5 8-9 11l1 47-2 5c3 2 7 3 10 2l-2-6-1-17 3-23c4-7 4-8 8-14l3 14c9 13 16 27 22 42l-1 7c3 2 7 2 10 0-6-16-10-32-20-48 6-5 11-12 13-21 13 5 18 2 28 1-1 8-3 15-2 23l-6 15 3 22-4 6c2 2 7 5 10 2l0-27c15-5 26-10 34-22 4-3 6-7 3-12-7-6-12-12-16-17 8-16 8-22 1-36l-4-11c7-1 9-2 15-5 9-3 6-7 4-10-7 0-14 2-17-3-3-4-5-9-12-8l-3-3c5-4 7-5 9-10 1-4-1-6-3-8-6-8-7-1-6 1l2 5c3 5-3 8-7 10-3-3-6-6-8-9-4-5 4-8 3-12 0-1-1-1-2-1m366 242c-3 8-8 20-12 32 8-4 12-6 19-13 5-5 6-8 0-13z" fill="none">
         <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="Rein.click" values="0; 953; 0" dur="20s" repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>
     
   </path>
  <path  stroke-width="1"  d="m366 242c-3 8-8 20-12 32 8-4 12-6 19-13 5-5 6-8 0-13z" fill="#DDDDDD"/>  
  </g>
         <text  x="320" y="190" font-size="10" font-family="Ariel" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="none" stroke="saddlebrown" stroke-width="0.5px" >Click me</text>
</svg>
```

Ниже пример анимация SVG иконки,выполненной несколькими патчами, поэтому рисование идет одновременно несколькими перьями. Обратите внимание, что между анимациями из-за одновременного рисования появилась пауза, которая равна разнице по времени между рисованием одним пером и рисованием несколькими перьями одновременно.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 
 width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
   <title>animation logo evernote</title> 
  <desc>Prohibited copying without specifying an indexed reference to the source svg-art.ru</desc>   
     
  
    <path class="path" fill="none" stroke ="black" stroke-dasharray= "700" stroke-dashoffset="0"  d="M113.5 56.2l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 20.6l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 64.6 116.2 59.7 113.5 56.2zM63.1 100.5c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 83.8 83.7 100.5 63.1 100.5zM63.1 29.3c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 44.5 81.7 29.3 63.1 29.3zM54.1 39.6l0 8.1 -2 1.9 -7.9 0L54.1 39.6zM74.4 87.9c0 0-2.1 0-5.3 0 -3.3 0-7.3-1.5-7.3-7.5 0-6 7.8-5.9 7.8-5.9v3.8c0 0-0.8-0.1-1.8-0.1s-1.8 0.5-1.8 2.3 1.7 3.1 1.7 3.1 2.7 0 5.2 0c2.4 0 2.6-2.8 2.6-2.8s0-2.1 0-4.5c0-2.4-2.4-4.8-6.5-4.8s-6.8-5.2-6.8-5.2 -0.1 3.3-0.1 5.5c0 0.5-1.6 4.8-10.9 3.4 -7.8-1.2-9-14.3-9-18.1 0-3.8 2.6-5.5 2.6-5.5h9.3l2-2.1v-6.9c0-1.7-0.3-3.7 4.2-3.7 4.5 0 6.4 3.4 6.4 3.4s3.6 0 5.9 0c2.3 0 6.7 1.7 7.6 3.1 0.8 1.5 3.8 3.2 3.8 22.2C84 86.7 74.4 87.9 74.4 87.9zM72.9 59.4c-1.8 0-2.3 3.1-2.3 3.1 0.9 0 6.6 1 6.6 1S74.7 59.4 72.9 59.4z">
 <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="1" values="700;0;700;" dur="10s" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
 </path>
    <text  x="98" y="17" font-size="11" font-family="Ariel" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="green" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5px" >Click me</text>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию для 'path', используя атрибуты dasharray \
>   dashoffset.

### Немного теории:

Эффекты рисования с чистого листа или наоборот плавное стирание линий достигаются использованием приема, когда взаимодействуют между собой:

- `stroke-dasharray = TotalLength()`
- `stroke-dashoffset = TotalLength()`, где

  `stroke-dasharray(5 5)` - прерывистая линия с длиной штриха и пробелами между ними равно 5 пикселей. При равенстве этих двух параметров можно записывать `stroke-dasharray(5)`

`stroke-dashoffset` - отступ от начала линии

`TotalLength` - полная длина линии.

Поэтому рисование с чистого листа начнется, при начальном условии, когда длина линии будет равна отступу от начала линии.   Отступ постепенно уменьшается и линия растёт. 
При стирании линии - отступ будет постепенно увеличиваться.

> Есть ли способ рассчитать длину правильно?

Есть, но и нюансы тоже есть.

```
<script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

**Ниже пример как рассчитать длину для вашего примера.**
 В принципе решение подойдет для других файлов SVG, для этого нужно будет, только подставлять свои значения в параметр "d"  `Path`

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
   
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="100%" height="100%" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
         d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6" /> 
</svg> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

Ниже реализация анимации стирания линий. Начало анимации- клик по иконке.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
   width="70" height="60" viewBox="-10 0 70 60"> 
  
    
   <path id="gear" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="604" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6"> 
  
   <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click-5s" 
         values="0;604;0" dur="10s" repeatCount="1"  fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear"/>
     </path>

 </svg>
```

Comment: В твоем примере длина тоже считается 600+, хотя по факту меньше 120 нужно скрипту. Проблема как раз в том, что 600+ неадекватная цифра и при простейших path'ах считается все хорошо(Например path с не прерывистой линией). Либо неадекватно воспринимает path браузер, а 600 и должно быть. Однако при таком составном - такая большая разница. А анимация у тебя сделана на smil. Этот вариант никак не подойдет, т.к. smil анимация уже depricated. Собственно я выбрал Snap, потому что он работает в ie (в отличие от css). Если какая то библиотека справляется лучше именно с этой задачей - рад буду узнать.

Comment: @CodingJediKnight  по первому вопросу depricated разработчики `chrome` уже как полтора года пишут, а SMIL живет и живет и нет ничего более постоянного чем временное. Посмотри caniuse они еще на 5 версий вперед отставляют в хроме smil. По второму вопросу подставь в свой скрипт 120 и посмотри, что получится - анимация будет выполнена на четверть. Потому что  `TotalLength()` взята из спецификации w3  Не найдешь ты никакую библиотеку, потому что все они будут использовать этот параметр. В твоем случае он будет всегда - 604

Comment: Я в своем примере как раз и показал, что на 604 - анимация происходит не правильно. Две анимации - в верхнем примере я посчитал `TotalLength()` , в нижнем я захардкодил значение 112, найдя его эмпирическим путем и анимация заиграла как надо.

Comment: @CodingJediKnight так я и предложил тебе поставить вместо переменной pathLength поставить константу 120, которую ты вычислил и посмотреть, что произойдет. И это не браузер криво отрабатывает, а такова иконка, которая нарисована несколькими патчами. Иконка одновременно рисуется несколькими перьями, поэтому фактическое время рисования намного меньше, чем если бы она рисовалась одним пером. totalLength вычисляется, как будто бы картинка нарисована одним пером и от этого тебя не спасет ни одна библиотека - всё лишнее время уходит в паузу.

Comment: @Чтобы проверить это запусти анимацию вперед и назад то есть на рисование и стирание линии. Вот между ними, как раз и будет пауза равная разнице по времени рисования одним пером или несколькими одновременно

Comment: @интересно. Уже хоть понимание приходит. А можно как то посчитать сколько перьев рисует? Я так понял это из-за того, что `path` "рваный"? ("которая нарисована несколькими патчами"). Точнее разбить `path` на кусочки из которых он собран и подсчитать наибольшую длину среди них. Я так понял как раз мы и получим 112?)

Comment: может быть можно сделать svg по-другому, не составным контуром? Проблема в том, что если дизайнер делает вектор не только на `path`, но и на `rect`, `line`, то с ними я уже не могу провести расчеты и заанимировать. Может можно эти другие фигуры трансформировать в контуры?

Comment: @CodingJediKnight ответил тебе в решении с JS насчет преобразования линий, прямоугольников в патчи см.  теорию https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=897  И еще, если получили знания, как-то решили часть проблем, не забудьте отметить галочкой решение

Comment: @ Проблему конечно так и не решили, но спасибо вам за вектор в направлении котором я буду копать. Раньше была тупиковая ситуация из-за чего полез сюда. После ваших объяснений появились идеи в каком направлении двигаться. Спасибо. Отметил про перья.

Answer (score 3):

### Решение JS

Такую иконку, как у вас, одним патчем d="M..." не нарисовать. Так как есть переходы от одного замкнутого контура к другому, и если не будет второго "M" (moveto) переход ко второму контуру с поднятием пера, то будут соединяющие линии между замкнутыми контурами.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" 
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="280" height="240" viewBox="-10 0 70 60" onclick="init(evt)"> 
 
 <script><![CDATA[
function init(evt)
{svgdoc=evt.target.ownerDocument
lengt=svgdoc.getElementById('gear')
vlom=Math.round(lengt.getTotalLength());
lengt.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',vlom.toString()+","+vlom.toString());
lengt.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset',vlom.toString());
obj=svgdoc.getElementById('a1');
obj.setAttribute('from',vlom.toString());

}
]]></script>
     
<g style="fill:none; stroke-width:1;stroke:black">
<path   id="gear" stroke-dasharray="0 0" stroke-dashoffset="0"  d="M59.1,32V13.6l0,0c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3v-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L47.2,1.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2h-0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l0,0H1.8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v8.7 M45.5,1.1v12.6c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h12.4 M58.2,42.2h-2.6
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4l1.9-1.7c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-3.9-3.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-1.8,1.8
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2v-2.7c0-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.9-0.9h-5.6c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v2.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2l-1.8-1.8
        c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.3,0l-3.9,3.9c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.8,1.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4H34
        c-0.6,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,0.9v5.6c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h2.6c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4L35,51.7c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.7s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7
        l3.9,3.9c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l1.8-1.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2v2.7c0,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9h5.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-2.6
        c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l1.8,1.8c0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.3,0l3.9-3.9c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L55.4,50
        c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4h2.6c0.6,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-0.9v-5.6C59.1,42.6,58.8,42.2,58.2,42.2z M46,42c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4
        s4-1.8,4-4S48.2,42,46,42z M16.2,59V26.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5l3.2-5.8c0.1-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.5s0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5l3.2,5.8
        c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V59 M11,59V15c0-0.6-0.3-1-0.8-1H1.7c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-0.8,1v44 M5,5h12 M20.4,5h4 M5,9h20 M55,19H35 M45,23
        H29 M55,28H29 M35,32h-6 M55,23h-6 M0.9,23H5 M0.9,32.7H5 M0.9,42H5 M0.9,51.8H5 M16.2,26.6h4.1h4.1 M20.3,59V26.6">
 <animate id="a1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" from="0" to="0" dur="15s" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced"/> 
</path>

</g>
</svg>
```

Выход один - прятать паузу. В этом скрипте, хоть финальных точек не остается по сравнению с применением библиотеки snap.svg